# Listing macros in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting the list all the commands and what key they a assigned to in Microsoft Word. However I am getting the problem of it only listing the macros/commands which I have made, and not the ones which come the software; such as `File Save` or `PrintPreviewAndPrint`.

The macro I am currently using is;

```
Sub ListKeyboardAssignments()
  Dim kb As KeyBinding
  For Each kb In KeyBindings
    If kb.KeyCategory = wdKeyCategoryNil Then
      Selection.TypeText (kb.Command + " " + kb.KeyString + " //Nil")
      Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
  Next kb
  For Each kb In KeyBindings
    If kb.KeyCategory = wdKeyCategoryDisable Then
      Selection.TypeText (kb.Command + " " + kb.KeyString + " //Disable")
      Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
  Next kb
  For Each kb In KeyBindings
    If kb.KeyCategory = wdKeyCategoryCommand Then
      Selection.TypeText (kb.Command + " " + kb.KeyString + " //Command")
      Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
  Next kb
  For Each kb In KeyBindings
    If kb.KeyCategory = wdKeyCategoryMacro Then
      Selection.TypeText (kb.Command + " " + kb.KeyString + " //Macro")
      Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
  Next kb
  For Each kb In KeyBindings
    If kb.KeyCategory = wdKeyCategoryMacro Then
      Selection.TypeText (kb.Command + " " + kb.KeyString + " //Prefix")
      Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
  Next kb
  For Each kb In KeyBindings
    If kb.KeyCategory = wdKeyCategoryFont Then
      Selection.TypeText (kb.Command + " " + kb.KeyString + " //Font")
      Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
  Next kb
  For Each kb In KeyBindings
    If kb.KeyCategory = wdKeyCategoryAutoText Then
      Selection.TypeText (kb.Command + " " + kb.KeyString + " //AutoText")
      Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
  Next kb
  For Each kb In KeyBindings
    If kb.KeyCategory = wdKeyCategoryStyle Then
      Selection.TypeText (kb.Command + " " + kb.KeyString + " //Style")
      Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
  Next kb
  For Each kb In KeyBindings
    If kb.KeyCategory = wdKeyCategorySymbol Then
      Selection.TypeText (kb.Command + " " + kb.KeyString + " //Symbol")
      Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
  Next kb
  For Each kb In KeyBindings
    If kb.KeyCategory = wdKeyCategoryPrefix Then
      Selection.TypeText (kb.Command + " " + kb.KeyString + " //Prefix")
      Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
  Next kb
End Sub
```

**Edit**

This macro also does not list all the macros the macros/commands which I have made. Any help in fixing this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sometimes it helps to specify the CustomizationContext - the document in which the keybindings (keyboard customizations) are saved. You might even need to address multiple documents if you want "everything". Examples of contexts: NormalTemplate, ActiveDocument, ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate. You'd also need to loop the members of the AddIns collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyBindings` only refer to your Customize Shortcuts.

If you just want a Table of all the Standard Word Based Shortcuts then you want to use:

```
 Application.ListCommands ListAllCommands:=True
```

This will open a new document and then insert a Table with the command name and the keystring.

Comment: Out of interest is there a reason it does not list the shortcuts for my macros. For example in the table it says `Normal.NewMacros.UpdateFields`, which is linked to `Shift+F9`, is unassigned.

Comment: I think it has something to with the `ListCommands` only referring to the shortcuts made by Microsoft. But I am not sure